# print hits and score from blast output

Tags: perl

I am trying to print each query and hit with only % id and score from a blast output file using this string

```
perl -we 'while (<>) {next if /^#/; @col = split /\t/; print join "\t", $col[0], $col[1], $col[2], $col[-1]}' SZ_vs_Self_20160510_2.txt >PROCESSED_SZ_vs_Self_20160510_2.txt
```

but I get this comment

> > was unexpected at this time

#### Deparsed Perl code

```
#!perl -w

while ( <ARGV> ) {
    next if /^#/;
    @col = split /\t/;
    print join "\t", $col[0], $col[1], $col[2], $col[-1];
}
```

Comment: Are you on MSWin? They have different quoting rules, you can't copy the command line directly  from *nix.

Comment: where can i find the suitable command lines

Answer (score 3):

At a guess you're using a Windows cmd prompt. You need double quotes around your code instead of single quotes

```
perl -we "while (<>) {next if /^#/; @col = split /\t/; print join qq/\t/, $col[0], $col[1], $col[2], $col[-1]}" SZ_vs_Self_20160510_2.txt > PROCESSED_SZ_vs_Self_20160510_2.txt
```

I would also suggest that this is rather too much code for a one-liner. Putting your code in a file would make it much easier to read

Comment: Although it could be written better as something like `perl -ne "print join qq/\t/, (split /\t/)[0..2,-1] unless /^#/" input.txt`

Comment: yes, i am using windows cmd prompt. i tried the double quotes but now the comment is: perl is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: and the same comment appears when I tried your suggested string

Comment: @Sara: Have you installed the Perl language?

Comment: I installed active perl for windows but i still get the same comment

Comment: I seems that perl was not properly installed, now i solved this problem and i used the string you mentioned above to extract hits and scores only. thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Borodin: i used another command to convert this generated txt file to a matrix, which is a very long one, but I get a comment that: unquoted string "t" may lash with future reserved word at -e line 1. do you know and better command to help reach my approach, many thanks again for your valuable help